# How to query REST API using strict typecasting

Tags: json, angular, rest, rxjs, observable

I cannot parse the output from the API (the array of projects is inside attribute `results`).Because TS says that `results` is not an attribute of the `Project` class.

Project class:

```
export class Project {
  project_id: string;
  project_name: string;
  project_code: string;
  project_lead: string;
  project_cost_center: number;
  project_number: string;
  budget: number;
  team: string;
  provision: boolean;
  project_groups: any;
  project_networks: any;
  applications: any;
  project_environments: any;
  subscription: string;
  created_at: string;
}
```

API response example:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/projects/COA/",
            "project_id": 57,
            "project_name": "Compliance Application",
            "project_code": "COA",
            "project_lead": "John Doe",
            "project_cost_center": "9005",
            "project_number": "900512I320",
            "budget": 600.0,
            "team": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/teams/TTA/",
            "provision": true,
            "project_groups": [],
            "project_networks": [
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/ip-network/23/"
            ],
            "applications": [
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/applications/COA/"
            ],
            "project_environments": [
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/environments/8/",
                "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/environments/7/"
            ],
            "subscription": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/subscriptions/128a4bb5-604d-11e9-86ee-88e9fe8080e6/",
            "created_at": "2019-04-16T13:37:05.293000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I'm using:

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.1
Node: 12.4.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.1
@angular/cli                      8.0.1
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.1
@schematics/angular               8.0.1
@schematics/update                0.800.1
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.30.0
```

My initial function looked like this:

```
// HttpClient API get() method => Fetch project list
  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(this.apiURL + '/projects')
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
```

Of course, I should use RxJS's `map` with the data from the GET operation to iterate then over `results` and yield the array of objects.

If I do

```
// HttpClient API get() method => Fetch project list
  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(this.apiURL + '/projects')
      .pipe(
        map(data => data.json().results),
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
```

Then I receive a message saying that the class `Project` doesn't have the attribute `json()`. Is this because I typecast the `.get()` method to `Project[]`? If so, how should I typecast it?

I expect to typecast this correctly, but I'm fairly new to Angular and documentation isn't helping.

Comment: HttpClient.get() applies res.json() automatically and returns. You no longer need to call this function yourself.

Comment: Even then, `data.results` doesn't work either, because I believe it's considering the output of `get()` as type `Project[]`. Should I typecast `get()` to something else?

Comment: Can you show your `Project` definition? Is it an `interface` or a `class`?

Comment: `.json()` really doesn't exist on type `HttpResponse` https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse.

Comment: I updated the question to show Project class and the API response format.

Comment: According your `Project` class and your API response,  `this.http.get<Project[]>(this.apiURL + '/projects')` does not return a array of `Project`. So remove the typing on the get or change it to something else corresponding your API response, then return the `data.results` in the `map` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be your API is not returning the array of projects. Its structure may be different (something like `APIResponse`). But in your method, you want to return an array of Projects.

If the issue is this, then, you should code something like this.

```
// HttpClient API get() method => Fetch project list
  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<APIResponse>(this.apiURL + '/projects')
      .pipe(
        map(data => data.results),
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
```

And your APIResponse class should be like this.

```
export class APIResponse {   
  count: number;
  next: any;
  previous: any;  
  results: Project[];
}
```

Comment: No, you have no clue what his `Project` looks like. You're just talking without a clue. This is not adding anything.

Comment: @Bjorn'Bjeaurn'S - As far as I understand, his API is not returning the array but he wants to return an array.

Comment: If that's the case, this is not really an Angular question is it? But even in that case, we need an example response from his server before we can start giving proper answers instead of guessing or assuming.

Comment: Actually, attribute `results` in the response JSON has an array of projects.

Answer (score 1):

The API does not return an array of `Project`, you have 2 solutions to work around your problem:

**First solution, don't use typed response:**

```
getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/projects')
    .pipe(
      map(data => data.results),
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

**Second solution, using a typed response**:

> Now HttpClient.get() returns an Observable of typed HttpResponse rather than just the JSON data.

```
export interface ApiProjectResponse {   
  count: number;
  next: any;
  previous: any;
  results: Project[];
}

getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
  // HTTP GET /projects returns an ApiProjectResponse
  return this.http.get<ApiProjectResponse>(this.apiURL + '/projects')
    .pipe(
      map(data => data.results),
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect a list of `Projects` as a result, you already have it in your data because you `typed` is as `Project[]`, which results in an `array of Project`.

With your data you can do things like `data.length` to see how many records of `Project` you have. This is basic array manipulation.

There is no `.results` on an `Array`. You can just `console.log(data)` to see the entire `Array` and work with that. `data.forEach()` walks over each `Project` inside your array etcetera. You can pass it to a `*ngFor="let project of projects"` and it'll traverse the `Array` for you.